# Does Deadpool have the highest degree of regeneration among all mutants?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

There are a few mutants with regenerative abilities. The most famous being Wolverine and Deadpool...
So, if the X-men cinematic universe is considered, it is quite obvious that Deadpool is the better regenerator.

Is it true in comics too?

Comment: I think you're going to need to define "faster" and why you think XCU Deadpool is "faster" than XCU Wolverine, who we've seen heal instantaneously from serious wounds...

Comment: @KutuluMike Never in the XCU movies has there been a scene where Wolverine regenerates any body part!

Comment: Well Wolverine has died and then healed more than once in the XCU, in X2 he was shot in the head and appears to die then regenerate then in The Wolverine he loses vitals for a minute while pulling the inhibitor thing out of himself. If the video game of X-Men Origins Wolverine counts he regenerates from being stripped to his adamantium skeleton in that. X23 would be a contender as well, she is supposed to have stronger regeneration abilities than Wolverine, the adamantium hinders his. She isn't in the XCU so far though.

Comment: @Probst Wolverine has taken much worse serious hits and healed,accepted. But here i am referring to specifically to regeneration.

Comment: In the comics, at least, wolverine's healing factor is effectively reduced by the adamantium, and is faster/better when he doesn't have it.

Comment: @MdDanishKhan except for the time when Jean Grey was literally tearing him apart atom by atom and he was regenerating faster than she could kill him. Plus, it took Deadpool quite a while to regrow that hand, so I wouldn't call it "fast"

Comment: It's also difficult to tell in the comics what parts of his "healing factor" are mutant and which parts of it are the curse of Thanos, intended to prevent him from ever seeing Death again.

Comment: @KutuluMike That's another good one I'd totally forgotten that one. Other people were instantly turned to dust but he healed so fast it basically did nothing to him.

Comment: It's obviously Claire Bennet, duh!

Comment: I think this was more answerable when you said “faster”. Highest degree?

Comment: Healing and regeneration are two different thing guys. Humans heal but do not regenerate. Stick to the question,please

Answer (score 3):

Deadpool's healing factor is generally considered faster than Wolverine's but it also varies from writer to writer. In some comics Wolverine has regenerated from a skeleton and Deadpool has regenerated after being liquefied.

Also notable is the fact that Deadpool's healing factor is constantly battling his cancer as well as healing other wounds. If it weren't for his cancer his healing factor would go berserk causing growths and eventually killing him.

Reference:
[Marvel wiki on Deadpool's powers.](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Wade_Wilson_(Earth-616)#Powers_and_Abilities)