# How fast does Wolverine heal compared to the average human?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine

From comic/movie sources, how many times faster could Wolverine heal than the average human? Non-canon counts if you need to use it.
What is his healing time rate compared to the average, healthy human?

For example, an average human heals at x 1

What does Wolverine heal at compared to that?

Comment: This is three questions, not one.

Comment: Dupe of [Is Captain America super-human?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87079/is-captain-america-super-human?rq=1), [Can Wolverine survive without oxygen?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14362/can-wolverine-survive-without-oxygen) and [Does Deadpool have the highest degree of regeneration among all mutants?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124514/does-deadpool-have-the-highest-degree-of-regeneration-among-all-mutants/137772#137772).

Comment: @Yasskier - I'd vote to close that in a heartbeat. Over time, the Avengers have included Asgardians, robots, humans, super-humans, mutants and, on at least one occasion, Squirrel Girl.

Comment: Deadpool isn't an Avenger, so asking about their "healing factor" wouldn't cover him. And how do you measure the healing factor for an entire team?

Comment: @phantom42 - Deadpool is an Avenger; http://uk.ign.com/articles/2015/10/08/deadpool-is-now-officially-an-avenger

Comment: To quote @WadCheber, "seven".

Comment: It's now one question, but that question is a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

### Insanely fast

During the course of the movies and comics, Wolverine was multiply time shot, stabbed, blasted with deadly rays, crushed and he healed those wounds in matter of seconds, in worst cases minutes.

Now to compare this to ordinary human, where 1 cm long, few millimetres deep wound can take 1 week to heal completely. Getting shot by bullet (assuming you survive) can take 3-6 months.

Lets compare this in pictures (thanks to @Kimberly W):

Here is Wolverine healing from nuclear blast healing in minutes:

> [image]

Here is 1 cm square shallow wound healed in month

> [image]

Comment: And nuclear blasts. Let's not forget those. Here he is literally recovering in minutes from being vaporized down to his adamantium skeleton: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/8/87323/1739946-275264_wolverine48_012_super.jpg